# Encontrar Elemento <tr> de um determinado conteúdo

Tags: javascript, regex

Gostaria de saber como encontrar um determinado elemento `<tr>` em uma tabela numerada. Por exemplo: Numa tabela em que cada linha `<tr>` tem suas células `<td>` numeradas de 1-5, contendo 4 linhas `<tr>`, se passo o número 15, tenho como resultado a 3ª linha `<tr>`, se passo o número 17, tenho como resultado a 4ª linha `<tr>`, e assim por diante.

Com `table.match(/<tr>/g)`, obtenho todos os 4 elementos `<tr>`, mas o que eu quero é obter apenas um elemento `<tr>`, como resultado final, de acordo com o critério numérico explicado acima.

O objetivo é aplicar um estilo na tag `<tr>`, um contorno, `outline: solid 1px red;`, para dar destaque.

```
var table = ['<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>
</tr>
</table>'];

table.match(/<tr>/g); // Me devolve todos os elementos <tr>
```

A tabela é originalmente a função abaixo que gera um Calendário. Já consegui destacar o ***dia atual***. Agora o desafio é ***fazer o mesmo com a semana atual***:

```
function Calendar(id, year, month) { 
  var elem = document.getElementById(id)

  var mon = month - 1
  var d = new Date(year, mon)
  var e = new Date();
  var weekDay = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  var months = ['January', 'Frebruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var table = ['<table><tr>']

  table.push('<th colspan = 4>' + months[mon] + '</th>' + '<th colspan = 3>' + year + '</th>' + '</tr><tr>')
  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ) {
    table.push('<th>' + weekDay[i] + '</th>')
  }
  table.push('</tr><tr>')

  for (var i=0; i<d.getDay(); i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')
  }

  while(d.getMonth() == mon) {

    if (d.getDate() == e.getDate()) { // Condicional para dar destaque ao dia atual
    table.push('<td class=day>'+d.getDate()+'</td>')
    } else {
    table.push('<td>'+d.getDate()+'</td>')
    }

    if (d.getDay() % 7 == 6) {
      table.push('</tr><tr>')
    }

    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)  
  }

  for (var i=d.getDay(); i<7; i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')
  }

  table.push('</tr></table>')

  elem.innerHTML = table.join('\n')
}

new Calendar("cal", 2015, 3);
```

Comment: Esse HTML não possui marcas distintas o suficiente para uso de regex, acho que uma solução que faça parse do fragmento vai atender melhor você.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sugiro fazer isso via HTML no Browser que é bem melhor que RegEx para ler HTML.
Não precisas de juntar ao DOM mas usando o Browser é mais seguro.

### Sugestão:

**Junta esse HTML a uma DIV:**

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = table;
```

**Junta o método de arrays aos métodos dos nodeLists para poderes usar `querySelectorAll`:**

```
NodeList.prototype.filter = Array.prototype.filter;
```

**Usa os métodos que usas no DOM nessa div:**

```
var value = input.value || 0;
var tds = div.querySelectorAll('td');
var match = tds.filter(function (td) {
    return td.innerHTML == value;
});
var resultado = match && match[0].parentNode;
alert(resultado.innerHTML); // vai mostrar só a linha que queres
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/zgbctL0o/

## EDIT:

Na sequência das clarificações adicionadas à pergunta o resultado final com o meu código foi adicionar no final dessa função estas linhas:

```
// mark this week
var today = (new Date()).getDate();
var tds = elem.querySelectorAll('td');
NodeList.prototype.filter = Array.prototype.filter;
var match = tds.filter(function (td) {
    return td.innerHTML == today;
});
if (match) match[0].parentNode.style.outline = 'solid 1px red';
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efuu16b8/

Comment: Achou que eu não fui muito claro na minha pergunta. O seu código devolve todas as células pertencentes a tag `<tr>`, igual ao do Miguel Angelo. O que eu preciso é mais ou menos ao contrário. Quero a tag `<tr>` que contém o número passado, não a série de células dentro dela. Se houver um modo mais simples de realizar isso, com regex, melhor.

Comment: @eden o meu código dá-te o `tr`. Só no alert juntei o conteudo para mostrar que era a `tr` certa. A variável `resultado` é o elemento tr. RegEx não é mais seguro que esta maneira que coloquei na resposta.

Comment: Com RegExp eu seria capaz de fazer um `replace` mais ou menos assim: `replace([<tr> desejada], '<tr style=outline=solid 1px red')`, aplicando um contorno na tag desejada. Como realizar isso com a sua solução?

Comment: @eden então podes usar `resultado.style.outline = 'solid 1px red';` Como vais usar essa tabela? já está no DOM? se sim ainda é mais fácil... ou tens em string e queres manter em string? explica melhor que junto exemplo também.

Comment: A tabela originalmente é um Calendário gerado por uma função que obtive [neste site](http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions) - "Create a function to create a calendar table for given Year/Month". É para aplicar o estilo ***durante*** ou ***após*** a geração da tabela, ainda dentro da função. Usando uma condicional, pude aplicar `table.push('<td class=day>'+d.getDate()+'</td>')` ***durante*** a geração da tabela. O que eu quero agora é dar o destaque a `<tr>` que representa a semana atual. Vou atualizar a pergunta para inserir a função Calendário.

Comment: @eden se tivesses colocado essa informação desde o inicio tinhas tido resposta com exemplo direto :) Aqui vai exemplo usando a minha solução: http://jsfiddle.net/qmLjmqsL/

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT**

Se a estrutura da tabela realmente não mudar:

- não conteiner tabelas dentro de tabelas
- o HTML estiver bem formado

então é possível usar regex para achar a tag de abertura do TR que contém a TD com o número desejado, como mostra o snippet abaixo:

```js
var num = 8;

var tabela = getTable();

var tabelaSubst = tabela.replace(RegExp("\\<\\s*tr\\s*\\>(?=((?!\\<\\s*\\/tr\\s*\\>).)*\\D\\s*0*"+num+"\\s*\\D)", 'g'), "<TR class='achou'>");

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = (tabelaSubst);

function encodeHtml(rawStr) {
    return rawStr && rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
        return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });
}

function getTable() {
    var table = ['<table>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>6</td><td>7</td><td> 08</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>'
    ];
    return table[0];
}
```

```css
.achou {
     color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

<sup>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/9jcxr4dh/3/)</sup>

**ANTIGO: usando parser de XML**

Você pode usar as APIs de parse de XML do broswer, e usar XPath para isso.

### Que API's são essas?

- [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser): permite fazer parse de documentos XML (HTML bem formado é XML), e criar uma AST, que contem a estrutura do documento
- [Document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate): permite fazer buscas usando XPath em um documento XML, que tenha sido obtido pelo `DOMParser`, ou até mesmo o documento carregado, ou seja, a própria DOM da página carregada

**Para dar suporta ao IE8**

O IE8 não suporta as API's acima diretamente... mas é possível, usar suas próprias:

- `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")` permite fazer parse de XML, além de aplicar XPath, tudo usando um único objeto

### XPath

Essa é a linguagem padrão para fazer consultas em documentos XML. Mas não se desanime pela palavra *Path* pois XPath está longe de ser um simples seletor de caminhos.

### Exemplo

```js
function getTrsModernBrowser() {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var frag = parser.parseFromString(getTable()[0], "text/xml");
    var xpathResult = frag.evaluate("//tr[td[text()=17]]", frag, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

    var trs = [];
    var result = xpathResult.iterateNext();
    while (result) {
        trs.push(result);
        result = xpathResult.iterateNext();
    }
    return trs;
}

function getTrsIE8() {
    var frag = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    frag.async = "false";
    frag.loadXML(getTable()[0]);
    frag.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
    var results = frag.selectNodes("//tr[td[text()=17]]");
    var trs = [];
    for (it = 0; it < results.length; it++)
        trs.push(results[it]);
    debugger;
    return trs;
}

function getTrs() {
    return window.ActiveXObject ? getTrsIE8() : getTrsModernBrowser();
}

var trs = getTrs();
for (var itTr = 0; itTr < trs.length; itTr++) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = encodeHtml(
        trs[itTr].outerHTML // browsers que suportam a API DOMParser
        || trs[itTr].xml // IE8
    );
}

function encodeHtml(rawStr) {
    return rawStr && rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
        return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });
}

function getTable() {
    var table = ['<table>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>'
    ];
    return table;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

<sup>[jsfiddle, pra que gosta de brincar lá, ao invés do snippet do SOPT](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/9jcxr4dh/2/)</sup>

### Dissecando a XPath acima do exemplo

- `//tr[td[text()=17]]`

  1. `//` ao início instrui o mecanismo a buscar nós em todos os níveis, e não somente na raiz
  2. `tr` é o elemento a ser encontrado, e poderia ser o nome de qualquer elemento
  3. `[ condição ]` esse operador se trata de uma assertiva sobre o elemento anterior, somente serão selecionados `tr`s com as características definidas dentro do operador `[]`
  4. `text()=17` indica que o texto do elemento sendo analisado deve ser o *número 17*. Atenção para o que eu disse: *"O NÚMERO 17"*... será usado comparador numérico. Portanto o texto do elemento poderá ser "017", "   00017   ", "17", etc.

Comment: Fiddle! Fiddle! Fiddle! :) Tou curioso, as aplicações são mais que muitas!

Comment: Calma! Eu vou adicionar informações... estou em processo de descoberta ainda. =)

Comment: @Zuul Agora a resposta já está mais consistente. Me diz o que achou... se tá boa, se falta eu explorar mais algum ponto... etc.

Comment: @Zuul Corrigido! Ao invés de `document.evaluate` devia ter usado `frag.evaluate`.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo - Achou que eu não fui muito claro na minha pergunta. O seu código devolve todas as células pertencentes a tag `<tr>`. O que eu preciso é mais ou menos ao contrário. Quero a tag `<tr>` que contém o número passado, não a série de células dentro dela. Se houver um modo mais simples de realizar isso, com regex, melhor.

Comment: O retorno não são os TDs... eu só imprimo os TDs a partir da propriedade `innerHTML` do próprio TR achado.

Comment: @eden Alterei o exemplo para imprimir o TR em si... qualquer coisa que você queira fazer com o TR é possível, mas você tem que me dizer exatamente o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo - Quero aplicar um estilo à linha inteira (`outline: solid 1px red;`). O motivo de um código mais simples, preferencialmente em regex, é que o software na qual o código vai rodar tem um suporte um tanto precário para JavaScript. Qualquer código mais complexo tende a não funcionar. A tabela invariavelmente terá o mesmo formato, só c/ números, e tudo o que eu preciso é pura e simplesmente a tag `<tr>` de abertura, nada mais, não precisa nem da tag de fechamento.

Comment: @eden Então você está na verdade esperando fazer um `replace` usando `regex`? Cara, tem como fazer usando `regex`, mas **só vai funcionar se a estrutura da tabela não mudar por nada nesse mundo**. =) Vou preparar uma aqui e postar.

Comment: @eden Com `regex` também não pode ter tabela dentro de tabela, se tiver já era... não tem como.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo - A tabela originalmente é um Calendário gerado por uma função que obtive [neste site](http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions) - "Create a function to create a calendar table for given Year/Month". O objetivo é realmente fazer um `replace()` com a regex.

Comment: Prontinho! Editei a resposta com uma regex pra fazer o replace. Daqui a pouco explico o que tá rolando nessa regex... vou ter que sair um momento.